# How to make the div and its content fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am making a div with a background image.In that div I want to add textboxes on some particular positions.Now whenever I resize my window the positions of the textboxes gets disturbed.
Here is the screenshot of what I am doing http://prntscr.com/8j4eel
I want the textboxes and image to b fixed no matter what the resolution or screen size is.

```css
#diagram {
  background: url("map.png") no-repeat center;
  width: inherit;
  height: 200px;
}
#diagram input[type="text"] {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 60px;
}
#left {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#right {
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}
#bottom {
  margin-left: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div id="diagram">
  <input type="text" id="left" />
  <input type="text" id="bottom" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="right" />
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/PPzyjj not sure i 100% understand what your trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fix the size of the container that's holding up all your elements. Try the below code. I have added `width:900px` to `#diagram`.

```css
#diagram {
  background: url("map.png") no-repeat center;
  width: inherit;
  height: 200px;
  width:900px;
}
#diagram input[type="text"] {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 60px;
}
#left {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#right {
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}
#bottom {
  margin-left: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div id="diagram">
  <input type="text" id="left" />
  <input type="text" id="bottom" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="right" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, it's:

```
position: fixed;
```